# Help identify this non-LEGO set - curvy slopes and stickers

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, clone-brands

I don't believe this is a LEGO set because there is no branding on the studs but hopefully someone recognizes the sticker and can tell me which set this is?

I'm looking for the exact set as I was handed down thousands of LEGO bricks for my kids with no instructions

[image: non-Lego build]

Comment: With those blank studs it is definitely not Lego. The few hollow ones look a lot like Megabloks to me.

Comment: first impression was "transformers" .. no idea why .. happy hunting! or a spaceship .. or it's a ninja turtle .. or batman .. yes, always batman .. now someone will spend a lot of time to disprove those theories and get you the right part .. you're welcome! would it be possible to get a photo from the bottom side? is it one piece? looks assembled. maybe from different sets?

Comment: Can you clarify your question. Are you asking to find out if it is Lego or not, or do you want to know the exact brand and set?

Answer (score 1):

This looks very much like the rear end of set 8669 Fire Spinner 360:

[image]

Only differences being that the pieces are counterfeit and the red on the stickers has been replaced with green. This is therefore, presumably, from a clone-brand version of this set.